# Can AutoHotKey V2 copy a URL?

Tags: autohotkey

I need to copy URLs from a browser navbar and paste them into Excel (both progs already running).

I'm trying to use AutoHotKey V2, but can't get it to select then copy the URL.

Would you expect the following to work?

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

^!9::{
SetKeyDelay 10,10
WinActivate "Edge"
Send "{LCtrl Down}L{LCtrl Up}"
Send "{LCtrl Down}C{LCtrl Up}"

WinActivate "Excel"
Send "{LCtrl Down}{V}{LCtrl Up}"

Return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

SetTitleMatchMode 2  ; if the window's title doesn't start with the specified title

^!9::{
WinActivate "Edge"
WinWaitActive "Edge"
Send "{Ctrl Down}l{Ctrl Up}"  ; capitals can trigger the Shift key
Send "{Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}"
Sleep(300)
WinActivate "Excel"
WinWaitActive "Excel"
Send "{Ctrl Down}v{Ctrl Up}"
}
```

Comment: Superb. Didn't know that capitals would actually trigger the Shift key. Many thanks :-)